# How do I add MAX(RowID)+1 when adding multiple records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, row, rowid

Tables:

1. `Orders` -- this stored `RowID`
2. `ExternalOrders` -- this is where I get some important order data from

I'm trying to add orders into the `Orders` table using data from `ExternalOrders`. However, I want to add multiple records at the same time and ensure that a new `RowID` number gets assigned to each new row.

For example, if the last `RowID` that currently exists in the `Orders` table is 1 then let the next row have a RowID of 2, then 3, 4...etc.

I've tried the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    RowID BIGINT,
    OrderID VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO Orders (RowID, OrderID)
    SELECT 
        MAX(O.RowID) + 1,
        E.Order_ID
    FROM 
        [DatabaseName].[dbo].[ExternalOrders] E
    LEFT JOIN 
        Orders O ON O.SaleDate = E.Sale_Date
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> Column 'DatabaseName.dbo.ExternalOrders.Order_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I also tried using the following as `RowID`:

```
DECLARE @NewRowID INT = (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM Orders) + 1
```

but this makes all records I insert have the same new RowID.

Important: there are already records in the `Orders` table so I want to resume RowID numbering from the last one present.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The error _**'DatabaseName.dbo.ExternalOrders.Order_ID' is invalid in the select list**_ is because you're using an aggregate function, but you're not grouping the non-Aggregate data (E.Order_ID).  When ever you work with aggregated data like this you should add a GROUP BY after any JOINS and WHERE clauses.  In this case, GROUP BY E.Order_ID

Answer (score 2):

You should likely be using an IDENTITY column for your auto incrementing ID. You do not provide a value for these columns when inserting into the table.

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (RowID INT IDENTITY, OrderDate DATETIME, CustomerID INT)

INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderDate, CustomerID) VALUES
(GETUTCDATE(), 1), (DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETUTCDATE()), 2)

SELECT *
  FROM @Orders
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for the Identity method! However, is there anyway to achieve what I'm asking for (continue numbering from last RowID value) where the numbering is always consecutive? The problem with Identity is lost values and risk of non-consecutive numbering.

Comment: This is not a problem with Identity; don't get hung-up on consecutive numbers, the ID's purpose is to provide a unique key - and that's *all*

Comment: To tack on to what @Stu commented, your identity values don't need to be consecutive. Depending on how you handle things such as deletes (most of the time soft deletes make sense - think of an IsDeleted BIT column or a nullable DeletedDateTime DATETIME column) allow you to leave the data intact anyway. If you do end up removing rows, that's fine, there are plenty of ways of still produce a full sequence.

Comment: @lenzo just to jump on the band wagon... why do you think you want consecutive ids? Whatever the reason is, you probably don't actually need them.